# Image clicked from Camera inside android app is blurred and has square pattern all over it

Tags: android, android-camera, blurry, cwac-camera

I am developing an app that uses phone camera to click pictures. On a few phones the camera images captured has square pattern as shown in the picture. I was earlier using the default Camera intent for opening the camera. Now I use the https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2 library. Also ths problem occurs only in portrait mode and not in landscape.

> ```
> **strong text**photoFile = Camera.createImageFile();
>
> Intent i=newCameraActivity.IntentBuilder(this)
>                    .skipConfirm()
>                    .facing(CameraActivity.Facing.BACK)
>                    .to(photoFile)
>                    .debug()
>                    .updateMediaStore()
>                    .build();
>
>            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_CLICK_IMAGE);
> ```

[image]

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/wiki/FAQ#why-image-captured-from-camera-is-blurred-or-low-quality

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the image is interpolated from a TV screen.
If you would take this image from a paper for example this is would not happen